# Highcharts donut ring coloring only selective part

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a highcharts ring using donut visualization.
The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HpdwR/1141/)
Now, I want to color 25% of the grey arc with same blue color as that of other 2 arcs.
How can I do that ?

The code that would essentially need to be changed is here :

```
data: [{
                name: 'fire',
                x: "Firefox",
                y: 33,
                color: 'grey'
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited with more information from OP.

To do this you can use the color.linearGradient approach. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/HpdwR/1142/).

```
{
            name: 'Browsers',
            data: [{
                name: 'fire',
                x: "Firefox",
                y: 33,
                color: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgb(124, 181, 236)'],
                        [0.25, 'rgb(124, 181, 236)'],
                        [0.50, 'gray'],
                        [0.75, 'gray'],
                        [1, 'gray']
                    ]
                }
            }
```

I am setting the linearGradient and removing the usual `x2` and `y2` as to me this looks better. Notice that it is still kind of fuzzy, however. You can play around with these settings to figure out what works best for your use case.

Old answer:
If you just want it to have the same color as the other 2 items do:

```
data: [{
                name: 'fire',
                x: "Firefox",
                y: 33,
                color: 'rgb(124, 181, 236)'
            }
```

The question is not very clear but this is how you would statically set it.

Comment: I want to color only 25% of the grey ring. That is the question. I do not want to color it 100% with blue. I know its a complicated requirement but thats how it is.

Comment: now thats great !! Only that I see the shading and possibly can remove that to have hard cutoff for the blue color. Thanks a lot